# Basic HTTP Authentication on HTTP Inbound Gateway Not Working

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-integration

I have an inbound gateway which I am trying to secure for BASIC HTTP Authentication using Java DSL.

```
IntegrationFlows
            .from(Http.inboundGateway("/support/toggleListener/{storageId}/{action}")
                    .headerExpression(HeaderKeys.STORAGE_ID, spelParser.parseExpression("#pathVariables.storageId"))
                    .headerExpression("action", spelParser.parseExpression("#pathVariables.action"))
                    .id("toggleListenerIn")
                    .requestMapping(new Consumer<RequestMappingSpec>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(RequestMappingSpec spec) {
                            spec.methods(HttpMethod.GET);
                            spec.methods(HttpMethod.POST);
                        }
                    })
                .get())
```

I am trying to secure the gateway using

```
@Component
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("SecurityConfig.configure called");
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").authenticated().and().httpBasic();
    }
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
          auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("test").password("test").roles("ADMIN");
    }
}
```

and

```
@Component
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer  extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

Both methods are getting fired (configure, configureGlobal), but the when I send a request to the gateway, the authentication is not kicking in.

Appreciate it if you can point out where I am getting it wrong or point to me Java DSL sample which uses BASIC Authentication for inbound gateway.

Comment: I wonder if your Security is configured properly for the `springSecurityFilterChain `: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.4.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#abstractsecuritywebapplicationinitializer. Please, share also `DEBUG` logs for the `org.springframework` category, when you perform request and sure that it should be *secured*.